# asp.net sending mail through office 365 smtp

Tags: asp.net, email, azure

I'm trying to set up a email notification for a asp.net project, but it doesn't seem to work. On localhost it gives me the following error

```
5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM
```

while on azure it triggers a suspicious login message over and over.
I tried multiple suggestions:

- port 25 instead of 587
- UseDefaultCredentials true or false
- enable and disable SSL

nothing seems to work. The suspecious activity mail is the closest I got so far. Here is my code

```
            var client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Port = 587;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Rachelle.XXXX@outlook.com", "password");
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            var message = new MailMessage("Rachelle.XXXX@outlook.com", "Rachelle_xxxxx@hotmail.com");
            message.Subject = "a ticket has been changed";
            message.Body = "Hi there, a ticket has been changed on Cronos. Please check Cronos for more details";

            message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            try
            {
                client.Send(message);
                return message;
            }
```